# Identity for fractional summation

Tags: fractions, floating-point

I would like to know if there's an identity to represent the following summation

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{x_i}{y_i}$

Where $x$ and $y$ are non integer values.
The result of this is being calculated using floating point arithmetic so I want to avoid all the repeated divisions which could accumulate rounding errors. Hopefully some identity exists such that I can avoid rounding errors.

Comment: I don't think so - this is similar to integrating $$\int{{f(x)\over g(x)}dx}$$ which does not have any "quotient rule" comparable to that for differentiating. So I do think any simplification would be possible.

Comment: Without any common property of the $y_i$ you won't have luck. But fortunately, *divisions* don't accumulate rounding errors (but the addition does).